# React JS which button is clicked how many times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 buttons and 1 h1 I need to count how many times the button is clicked and display the button name with no. of count it clicked in h1 with the name of the button. Right now I am getting the name of button correctly but not able to display the click count for the button. please help

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

export default class App extends Component {
  state={
    button:"",
    countClick:0
  }

buttonClick=(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({button:e.target.name, countClick:this.state.countClick+1});
}

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>
          {this.state.button} clicked {this.state.countClick} times
        </h1>
        <button name="Button 1" type="button" onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button 1</button>
        <button name="Button 2" type="button" onClick={this.buttonClick}>Button 2</button>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Thank You

Comment: do you need to count clicks for each button separately or together? because you are incrementing the same value here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notice points:

- build an Array to store each button's click amount status.
- optionally use `{id, value}` structure for the array items, since we need to display the clicked button with its click amount.
- use `map()` to prevent from repeating yourself about `<button />`.
- pass the identity index as a param inside the nested handler function.

---

Full code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const amount = 2;

export default function App() {
  const [clickList, setClickList] = React.useState(
    [...Array(amount).keys()].map(x => ({ id: `Button ${x + 1}`, value: 0 }))
  );
  const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = React.useState("");
  const buttonClick = idx => e => {
    const result = [...clickList];
    result[idx].value += 1;
    setClickList(result);
    setActiveButton(e.target.name);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        {`${activeButton} clicked ${clickList.find(x => x.id === activeButton)?.value ?? 0} times`}
      </h1>
      {clickList.map((x, idx) => (
        <button name={x.id} type="button" onClick={buttonClick(idx)}>
          {x.id}
        </button>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

setState can take an object or a callback with previous state as parameter.
Change your setState like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({button:e.target.name, countClick: prevState + 1}));
```